# Rather than storing JOptionPane input as a variable and passing to a method. Can you input variable directly into method?

Tags: java, joptionpane

Im trying to prompt the user to input two numbers from a dialog box using JOptionPane and then calling a method to return their value.

I'm trying to convert the string value JOptionPane returns into an integer using Integer.parseInt() but I can't get it to work.

Any hints where im going wrong?

Thanks!

```
    /**
 * 
 */
package methodsWeekThree;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * @author kylemoffett
 *
 */
public class ReturnMethodExcersiseOne {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Please input num1 and hit enter: ");

        System.out.println("Please input num2 and hit enter: ");

        System.out.println(additionCircuit(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input num1:"))),
                Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input num2:")));

    }// end main

    /**
     * This method adds two numbers and returns the value
     * 
     * @param num1 - first number to add
     * @param num2 - second number to add
     * @return - total of the addition
     */
    public static int additionCircuit(int num1, int num2) {

        int total;

        total = num1 + num2;

        return total;

    }// end additionCircuit

}// end class
```

Comment: Store JOptionPane values and then pass those values to the additionCircuit method

Comment: You never requested user input. Use the scanner class.

Comment: @NitinBisht I was thinking I had to do that, was just being lazy and hoping I could pass them straight through. Thanks!

Comment: @Smartsav10 The JOptionPane shows a dialogue box to prompt the user for input

Comment: @KyleMoffett no problem, I have added an answer for the same kindly check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
public class ReturnMethodExcersiseOne {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Please input num1 and hit enter: ");
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input num2:"));
        System.out.println("Please input num2 and hit enter: ");
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input num2:"));
        
        System.out.println(additionCircuit(num1, num2));

    }// end main

    /**
     * This method adds two numbers and returns the value
     * 
     * @param num1 - first number to add
     * @param num2 - second number to add
     * @return - total of the addition
     */
    public static int additionCircuit(int num1, int num2) {

        int total;

        total = num1 + num2;

        return total;

    }// end additionCircuit

}// end class
```

**Explanation:**

1. It is good to store `JOptionPane` values before passing it to `additionCircuit` method to avoid brackets issue.

Comment: Why would that make a difference?

Comment: Your code will work and is more readable than OP's but that explanation is blatantly false.

Comment: It does not make any difference if you store a return value into a variable before passing it into another function as a parameter, or if you just nest the function calls. At least, as long as you don't get confused by the nested function calls and mess up your brackets, which is what happened to OP. See my answer, which has working (albeit nasty and unreadable) code for doing this in a single line.

Comment: @Taschi you are right it will not matter whether values are stored or not before passing to the method. Secondly writing in a single line will lead to error most of the time with an increase in brackets as with OP. Hence I used variables to avoid bracket mistakes. Anyway I appreciate you found bracket error :)

Answer (score 1):

The nesting of your brackets is wrong.

```
System.out.println(additionCircuit(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input num1:")),
Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input num2:"))));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative method that displays a `JOptionPane` once only, rather than twice.

```java
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class ReturnMethodExcersiseOne {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        JLabel num1Label = new JLabel("num1");
        panel.add(num1Label, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        JTextField num1TextField = new JTextField(6);
        panel.add(num1TextField, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        JLabel num2Label = new JLabel("num2");
        panel.add(num2Label, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        JTextField num2TextField = new JTextField(6);
        panel.add(num2TextField, gbc);
        JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(panel);
        JDialog dlg = optionPane.createDialog("Prompt");
        dlg.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
                int num1 = Integer.parseInt(num1TextField.getText());
                int num2 = Integer.parseInt(num2TextField.getText());
                System.out.println(additionCircuit(num1, num2));
                ((JDialog) e.getSource()).dispose();
            }
            
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                int num1 = Integer.parseInt(num1TextField.getText());
                int num2 = Integer.parseInt(num2TextField.getText());
                System.out.println(additionCircuit(num1, num2));
            }
        });
        dlg.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dlg.setSize(200, 200);
        dlg.setVisible(true);
    }// end main

    /**
     * This method adds two numbers and returns the value
     * 
     * @param num1 - first number to add
     * @param num2 - second number to add
     * @return - total of the addition
     */
    public static int additionCircuit(int num1, int num2) {
        int total;
        total = num1 + num2;
        return total;
    }// end additionCircuit
}
```